# How to use boost ptree to parse wide byte strings like chinese ? boost version is boost_1_64_0

Tags: c++, json, boost

My code is here:

```
// Using chinese
std::string c1 = "中文1";
std::string c2 = "中文2";

// write json text
ptree pt_write_;
pt_write_.put("1", c1);
pt_write_.put("2", c2);
std::ostringstream os;
write_json(os, pt_write_);
std::string a = os.str();

// read json text
ptree pt_r;
std::istringstream is(a);
read_json(is, pt_r);
std::string b = pt_r.get<std::string>("2");
```

There is one problem, when I run the code I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgegZ.png) error. How can I solve it?

Comment: Show the error as text not the print-screen of the code in boost that throws without explaining what is the contents of e.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In the file boost\property_tree\json_parser\detail\narrow_encoding.hpp
```

step 1:

replace trail_table function while the value in the array is -1, replace the value to 1;

step 2:

replace code `if (cur == end || !is_trail(*cur))` to -> `if (cur == end/* || !is_trail(*cur)*/)` then you get ok